# list index out of range in python : IndexError

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am very new to Python and have the below error. Can someone help me with this please? Thanks.

**code: In file Exporter.py**

```
def __get_mailIdList(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        emailId_list=filter(lambda l: not l.startswith('#'), [line.strip() for line in f])
        emailIds = OrderedDict((l[0],l[1]) for l in (l.split(':') for l in emailId_list))
    emailIds['TOTAL']='TOTAL'
    return emailIds
```

**Error:**

```
File "Exporter.py", line 33, in __get_mailIdList
    emailIds = OrderedDict((l[0],l[1]) for l in (l.split(':') for l in emailId_list)) 

  File "/opt/Continuum/Anaconda2/envs/prod2/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.__update(*args, **kwds)

  File "/opt/Continuum/Anaconda2/envs/prod2/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 571, in update
    for key, value in other:

  File "Exporter.py", line 33, in <genexpr>
    emailIds = OrderedDict((l[0],l[1]) for l in (l.split(':') for l in emailId_list))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: this code is messy and unpythonic, try to not cram so much on each line. with that being said take a look at `emailId_list` and see if it matches your expectations of what it is supposed to look like

Comment: please explain specifically what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: What does your file look like?  Can you give a few example lines?

Comment: Maybe one of the lines does not contain `:` and it fails at `l[1]` because `l` only contains 1 element?

Comment: what `emailId_list` is containing?